# É possível em PHP recuperar parte de uma string utilizando a mesma notação que Python?

Tags: php, string

Tenho a seguinte variável para exemplo:

```
$teste = 'Uma frase qualquer!';
```

Em *Python*, para mim recuperar a palavra `frase`, eu utilizaria a notação `variavel[inicio:fim]`:

```
teste = 'Uma frase qualquer!'
print(teste[4:9]) # frase
```

É possível utilizar a mesma notação em *PHP*?

Comment: Com a função [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) você consegue efeito similar, porém não tão elegante quanto o do python.

Comment: Creio que não, o tipo de dado _string_ está implementada de forma diferente em **PHP** e **Python**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, até porque PHP não trata *strings* como só mais uma coleção de dados (caracteres) em sequência, como Python faz.

A única forma é usar uma função como a [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). A não ser que queira escrever um compilador que leia uma nova forma e gere o código PHP puro.

Mas tem uma pegadinha aí. Em Python você usa a posição de início e de fim do que deseja pegar. A função do PHP indica a posição inicial e quantas posições deve pegar no total. Então ficaria assim:

```
print substr($teste, 4, 5);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Substr.php).

Comment: Essa duvida surgiu depois que vi na documentação: `$string = 'bar'; echo "The last character of '$string' is '$string[-1]'.\n";` que no caso retorna o ultimo caractere.

Comment: Se for pegar só um caractere dá certo, mas não tem como pegar uma faixa.

Answer (score 1):

Em php você faz assim:

```
$texto= 'Uma frase qualquer!';
                    //O primeiro parâmetro é de onde começa, o outro é onde termina
echo substr($texto, 0, 10);
```

Também é possível fazer:

```
echo substr($texto, -10);
//Isso pegará os caracteres a partir do último para esquerda

echo echo substr($texto, 11);  //Mostrará todos após o index 11

echo substr($texto, 11, 9)  //Isso mostrará do index 11 até 9 letras após ele, ex:    
$texto = "eu não sou besta pra tirar onda de herói";
echo substr($texto, 11, 9);  // besta pra
```

Fonte: http://codare.aurelio.net/2007/05/22/php-cortando-strings-substr/